# Retrieve docx footnotes with officer package

Tags: r, officer

I have read a docx file into R using [officer package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/officer.pdf). Here is the code I used:

```
library(officer)
files = list.files()
doc <- read_docx(files[1])
content = docx_summary(doc)
```

The resulting dataframe contains all paragraphs, but not the text in the footnotes. Is there any way to retrieve that, too?

Comment: Would something like `xml_text(xml_find_all(doc$footnotes$get(), "*"))` meet your needs?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: And what exactly "*" ` in  xml_find_all(doc$footnotes$get(), "*"` means? I understand that doc$footnotes$get() retrieves a series of xml nodes, but why * ?